# Nim: Can't access fields of object returned by a procedure

Tags: lexer, nim-lang

I was trying to write a lexer in Nim. Sorry, if this sounds a bit idiotic because I started using nim yesterday, so my problem is that I created a type such as what follows

```
import position

type
  Error* = object
    pos_start : position.Position
    pos_end : position.Position
    name: string
    details: string
```

then I went on to create a procedure that returns an instance of this type,

```
proc IllegalCharacterError*(pos_start : position.Position, pos_end : position.Position, details : string) : Error =
  return Error(pos_start: pos_start, pos_end: pos_end, name: "IllegalCharacterError", details: details)
```

Now, everything works fine except when I, from another module, try to access fields of this returned instance I get error

```
from errors import nil
from position import nil

var current_char = "2"
let pos = position.Position(idx: -1, ln: 0, col: -1, fn: fn, ftxt: text)
let error = errors.IllegalCharacterError(pos, pos, current_char)
echo error.name
```

The last line is the one that throws the error and following is the error that appeared during compilation

```
Error: undeclared field: 'name' for type errors.Error [declared in C:\Users\Mlogix\Desktop\testNim\errors.nim(4, 3)]
```

Thanks, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, finally after an hour I realized that my fields weren't public. For anyone from the future, I changed my type code to

```
import position

type
  Error* = object
    pos_start* : position.Position
    pos_end* : position.Position
    name*: string
    details*: string
```

and it worked. Hooray.